# Linq To Objects, List<Items>, where Items consist of List<Items2>

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have `List<Book>`, where

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Author> Authors {get; set;}
}

public class Author
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

I need to get `<FirstName, BooksCount>`, for each author count number of books.
I understand, that I need to use GroupBy, but get `List<Author>` instead of  `<FirstName, BooksCount>`.

Comment: Can you share the code which you have writtern?

Comment: Usually in the books/authors exercise scenario there is only one author per book. Are you sure you have this right?

Comment: @Crowcoder may be the OP means by authors the proofreaders/reviewers too.

Comment: @Sajid it could be but this scenario is usually homework. And the given design does not allow multiple books per author so I feel it is possible the implementation is incorrect but maybe not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. I'm groupping by FullName instead of FirstName, because i highly doubt FirstName could be unique identifier. FullName is better, but still could not be unique. You could change `.GroupBy(a => $"{a.FirstName} {a.LastName}")` to `.GroupBy(a => a.FirstName")` if you want

```
            List<Book> books = new List<Book>() { 
            new Book { Name = "b1", 
                Authors = new List<Author>() { 
                    new Author { FirstName = "a1fn", LastName = "a1ln" }, 
                    new Author { FirstName = "a2fn", LastName = "a2ln" } } 
            }, 
            new Book { Name = "b2", 
                Authors = new List<Author>() { 
                    new Author { FirstName = "a1fn", LastName = "a1ln" } } 
            }, new Book { Name = "b3", 
                Authors = new List<Author>() { 
                    new Author { FirstName = "a2fn", LastName = "a2ln" } } 
            }, new Book { Name = "b4",
                Authors = new List<Author>() {
                    new Author { FirstName = "a2fn", LastName = "a2ln" } }
            } };

            var result = books.SelectMany(b => b.Authors)
                .GroupBy(a => $"{a.FirstName} {a.LastName}")
                .Select(g => new { FullName = g.Key, BooksCount = g.Count() });
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere and i've mentioned in my answer that it would be preferable for author to have Unique identifier so we could group by it :)

Comment: @HimBromBeere http://joxi.ru/82QOdjkcwN0Ppr am i wrong with those results?..

Comment: Yes, you´re right. Although you omit the books, the authors are contained multiple times in your list and you can count for duplicates. Missed that.

Comment: With my answer i assume the following "One author could be stated 0 or 1 times in the `Authors` list, `Author` is Unique by pair of `FirstName` and `LastName`". So there's no need to iterate through concrete books : we need only know how many times we've encountered this exact `Author`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some Books are written by several Authors.

You have a sequence of Books written by one or more Authors, and you want a method to transform this sequence into a sequence of Authors with the Books the wrote.

```
Book     Author(s)
  A      author1
  B      author2
  C      author3
  D      author1, author3
  E      author2, author3
```

We'll first flatten it: get combinations [Book, Author], then group by the same Author:

After Flatten:

```
 Book    Author(s)
  A      author1
  B      author2
  C      author3
  D      author1,
  D      author3
  E      author2,
  E      author3
```

After Group by same Author:

```
Author      Books
author1     A, D
author2     B, E
author3     C, D, E
```

Flattening is done using SelectMany
Making groups of items where every group member has a common value is done using GroupBy

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = ...
var authorsWithTheirBooks = books.SelectMany(book => book.Authors,

    // parameter ResultSelector: take every [book, author] combination to make one new
    (book, author) => new
    {
        Book = book,
        Author = author,
    })

    // now make groups with same Author:
    .GroupBy(flattenResult => flattenResult.Author,

    // resultSelector: take every author, and the books of this author to make one new
    (author, booksOfThisAuthor => new
    {
        Author = author,
        Books = booksOfThisAuthor.ToList(),
    });
```

Well, you don't want all books of this author, you only want the number of books:

```
    (author, booksOfThisAuthor => new
    {
        Author = author,
        Books = booksOfThisAuthor.Count(),
    });
```